# Akamai caching for Angular SPA application

Tags: angularjs, angular, akamai

We have akamai cache enabled for angular application & below are the extensions in application

[image]

Context is to optimize the loading of application via akamai caching but when akamai policy was applied it seems application behaved weird & could not navigate appropriatly. Ask is to get clue in angular application can we cache all files to enable optimized loading of application.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript files could affect the application. If the JavaScript files are often updated, it would be better to consider the shorter cache TTL at CDN side or purge the cache when it's refreshed.

Other media files such as images, fonts would be better to be cached at CDN if these files don't have the personal information. In general, these files don't affect the application behaviors.